# How can I use Reflection to get all fields of particular interface type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, interface

Consider following interfaces

```
public interface ISample 
public interface ISample2 : ISample

public class A
{
    [Field]
    ISample SomeField {get; set;}

    [Field]
    ISample2 SomeOtherField {get; set; }
}
```

Suppose there are various classes like class A and various Fields like SomeField and SomeOtherField. 
How can I get a list of all such Fields which are of type ISample or other interfaces derived from ISample (like ISample2)

Comment: None of those are fields.  Those are all properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a combination of `Reflection` and `Linq` to do something like this:

```
var obj = new A();
var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties()
                    .Where(pi => typeof(ISample).IsAssignableFrom(pi.PropertyType))
```

You must be extra cautious when dealing with generics. But for what you ask this should be good

If you want to get all classes that have at least one property returning a child of `ISample` you will have to use assemblies, for instance, the Currently executing

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties().Where(pi => // same code as the sample above)
```

In case you have several assemblies to probe you can use something like this

```
IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies = ....
var properties = assemblies
            .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes().SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties()...))
```

Comment: You don't need an instance of `A`, you can just use `typeof(A).GetProperties()...`

Comment: @CraigW. yes i know i was just trying to be very explicit to avoid any confusion. Thanks for the comment though i really forgot to say that

Comment: As mentioned earlier, there are various classes like class A.@CraigW , @Luiso

Comment: so you want to get all classes that have properties of a type that is assignable from the `ISample`? In that case an `Assembly` will have to be used.

Comment: Your [IsAssignableFrom()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx) is backwards.  `typeof(ISample).IsAssignableFrom(pi.PropertyType)`.  `public virtual bool IsAssignableFrom(
 Type c
)` -> c is derived either directly or indirectly from the current instance or The current instance is an interface that c implements.

Comment: Thanks @ErikPhilips i will correct my answer accordingly